# Need to change div's contents while slider changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jquery banner needs to some fixes. I have used echo slider for banner. when banner image change to another image, we need to change the content in a div which is not inside the slider's boundary. The Div is separate div (No connection with slider ).

I have tried with the code. i just put if statement based on slider's navigation.

My codes affected the 1st banner image only. it doesnt affect next banner

Help me

Here below my codes

```
<div class="echo-nav">
<a rel="0" class="echo-control active" href="javascript:;">1</a>
<a rel="1" class="echo-control" href="javascript:;">2</a>
<a rel="2" class="echo-control" href="javascript:;">3</a>
<a rel="3" class="echo-control" href="javascript:;">4</a>
<a rel="4" class="echo-control" href="javascript:;">5</a>
<a rel="5" class="echo-control" href="javascript:;">6</a>
</div>

<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.echo-nav a.active').attr('rel')=='0'){
            $('#app_info').text('Some dummy contents for one');                 
        }
    else if($('.echo-nav a.active').attr('rel')=='1'){
            $('#app_info').text('Some dummy contents for Two ');                    

              }
});
```

Comment: (offtopic) you collected 6! unaccepted answers, why?

Comment: That is not true, if I set the second `a`- class `active` - works really fine: http://jsbin.com/ipohuq/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: but we cant put directly. its just slider and it runs automatically. so when the second slider has active, div content should changes. but i dont get the content changes for the 2 slider. as well as 3, 4 and 5

Comment: Look at my answer and guide me to make your desired corrections

Comment: You should than show me your slider code, so I can implement the changes. Otherwise your question and my help is useless.

Comment: http://ragu.designs.asites.qa.sirahu.net/adblend-final-2/

can you check the url...
so that you can get clear what i need...
for now i didnot hosted my latest scripts

Comment: ok... and where is the slider that matches your question? I cannot find it.

Comment: #app_info this id's content should be changed while the slider changes.
I have separate contents for each slider. But i dont have any idea about that

Comment: #app_info id is left section which is beside the slider

Answer (score 0):

You can do it another (easy) way:

### *[demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uzedat/edit#javascript,html,live)*

```
var contents = [
    'Some dummy contents for 1',
    'Some dummy contents for 2',
    'Some dummy contents for 3',
    'Some dummy contents for 4',
    'Some dummy contents for 5',
    'Some dummy contents for 6'
];

var activeRelN = $('.echo-nav a.active').index(); // get index N (0,1,2,3...)

$('#app_info').html(contents[activeRelN]);
```

Comment: This is another way what i did. It also works for first slider only.
i would also tell something about that. echo-nav has 6 anchor tags. we cant put active class in those 6 anchor tags by manually. This is just slider which means its dynamically changing the active class and indicates which slider is on. So first one only affected. And 2,3, etc not works when the active class changes dynamically one to another anchor tag .